# Session.getAttribute("id) in Scala PlayFramework

Tags: scala, session, playframework

When using JSP and JAVA, I was able to use session.setAttribute("id") after logging into system and remember the user id while session lasts and call by session.getAttribute.

Do we have/use similar logic in Play/Scala? If so, can anyone show me how in details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play is stateless by default so obviously it does not store session on server.  Instead cookies are used to exchange session data between client and server. You can read about it in their documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaSessionFlash